# NewRelic Azure Monitoring Intervals

Tags: azure, newrelic

I am trying to find documentation of NewRelic's monitoring intervals for Azure Websites/Cloud Services.

Currently, we use standard Azure monitoring - but it is always 5-10 minutes behind (as stated in their [documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-monitor/)).

Anyone who is using NewRelic Monitoring in Azure (websites/services) - can you shed some light on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

New Relic has a separate add-on within Azure for monitoring Azure Websites which harvests data in 1 minute increments.  As the data ages, it rolls up to hour-long increments.  The [Standard subscription](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/accounts-partnerships/accounts/account-maintenance/data-retention) that comes with using the New Relic Add-on aggregates data after 3 days and metric data is stored for 14 days.

Here is some more information regarding New Relic and Azure

[Using New Relic with Azure Websites](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/azure-websites)

[Using New Relic with Azure Cloud Services](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/azure-cloud-services)

[Using New Relic with Azure Websites in Microsoft's new version of the Azure Portal](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/azure-preview-portal)

Answer (score 0):

As a FYI... Azure now provides monitoring data in 1 minute increments. More information at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-metrics

Comment: please copy a bit of data from the website.  If they delete the webpage, your answer is meaningless.